# xml and php getting tag elements with certain element and outputting

Tags: php, xml

I am have two xml files.. I first get one and loop through it then I need to take an id from the first xml file and find it in the second one and echo out the results associated with that id. If I were to do this with SQL I would simply do this:

```
$query = (SELECT * FROM HotelSummary WHERE roomTypeCode = '$id') or die();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
   $name = $row['Name'];
}
echo $name;
```

How can I do this is in xml and php??

Comment: You can interact with an XML file in a similar manner to the way you would with javascript on a webpage - http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php . The DOMDocument object supports  the getElementById() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to read the [DOMDocument documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/de/class.domdocument.php).
It's quite heavy but also powerful (not always clear what happens, but the Internet shold always give you a solution)

You can simply walk through your first document, finding your Id and then find your DOMElement via an XPath.

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('1.xml');

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('article') as $node) {
    // your conditions to find out the id
    $id = $node->getAttribute('id');
}


$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('2.xml');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$element = $xpath->query("//*[@id='".$id."']")->item(0);

// would echo "top_2" based on my example files
echo $element->getAttribute('name');
```

Based on following test files:

1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<articles>
    <article id="foo_1">
        <title>abc</title>
    </article>
    <article id="foo_2">
        <title>def</title>
    </article>
</articles>
```

2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tests>
    <test id="foo_1" name="top_1">

    </test>
    <test id="foo_2" name="top_2">

    </test>
</tests>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use SimpleXML to create an object representation of the file.  You can then loop through the elements of the Simple XML object.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the format of the XML file:

Assuming it is:

```
<xml>
    <roomTypeCode>
        <stuff>stuff</stuff>
        <name>Skunkman</name>
    </roomTypeCode>
    <roomTypeCode>
        <stuff>other stuff</stuff>
        <name>Someone Else</name>
    </roomTypeCode>
</xml>
```

It would be something like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('xmlfile.xml');
for($i = 0; $i < count($xml->roomTypeCode); $i++)
{
    if($xml->roomTypeCode[$i]->stuff == "stuff")
    {
        $name = $xml->roomTypeCode[$i]->name;
    }
}
```

That connects to the XML file, finds how many roomTypeCode entries there are, searches for the value of "stuff" within and when it matches it correctly, you can access anything having to do with that XML entry.